# Memory Error on my crop and stack program

Tags: python, debugging, memory-management, directory, python-imaging-library

I recently started learning programming and have finally written my first program. This program input all the images in a folder and crops them to a certain size. Then these images are are stacked vertically to produce a new image.
So I have been running test images through my program and it appeared to work fine. But I have only been using 10 images at a time. When I decided to finally try the program for the purpose I intended, which requires over 500 images, the program crashes. I get the MemoryError.
Since I just started, I wrote together whatever I thought would work, whether it was the most efficient method or not. If anyone has time, are there any blatant things in my code that just consume way too much resources.

```
from PIL import Image
from natsort import natsorted
import glob

# Convert coordinate list into variables
print("Type in the coordinates for the upper left (x1,y1) and bottom right (x2,y2) points")
coordinates = list(map(int, input("Separate values with a space (x1 y1 x2 y2): ").strip().split()))[:4]
x1, y1, x2, y2 = coordinates
print("Generating image...")

# creating lists to hold the initial files and the edited files
image_list = []
cropped_images = []

# Accessing all the files using the glob module
# The function natsorted sorts values the way Windows does
# Opens all the files with the variable img in folder and adds them one by one to a list named image_list
for filename in natsorted(glob.glob("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\One Dimensional Reaction Diffusion Program\\data\\*.tiff")):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(img)

# for each image in the image_list
# selected_region from previous user input
# cropped_region applied the crop function for the images in the selected region
    # Cropping function
    selected_region = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
    cropped_region = image.crop(selected_region)  # unsure if this is correct
    # If cropped area is vertical, rotate into horizontal position
    if (y2 - y1) > (x2 - x1):
        rotated_image = cropped_region.rotate(90, expand=1)  # Expand 1 ensures image isn't cut off while rotating
    else:
        rotated_image = cropped_region  # Does nothing if image is horizontal
    cropped_images.append(rotated_image)  # appends all rotated_images to the list cropped_images

# Size of each individual image
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in cropped_images))

# Final image dimensions
max_width = max(widths)
total_height = sum(heights)

# Create a new colored image (RGB)
new_img = Image.new('RGB', (max_width, total_height))

# Stacking function
# to offset horizontally, need to change final image dimensions to sum(widths) and max(heights)
# and change new_im.paste(img, (x_offset,0))
y_offset = 0  # Initial position is 0
for img in cropped_images:  # Not sure if img will cause conflict because img used in above for loop
    new_img.paste(img, (0, y_offset))  # (x,y) indicates which direction to offset in
    y_offset += img.size[1]  # location of new image is y_offset (which had position 0) + the height of the image

new_img.save("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\One Dimensional Reaction Diffusion Program\\output\\stacked.tiff", quality=95)
```

Comment: What's the total size of the 500 images? Looks like you are storing all completely in memory.

Comment: You could write the cropped versions to temporary files, free their memory and then re-read them one at a time. It will be significantly slower, but use much less memory.

Comment: @jordanm I initially had it like this where I saved them as separated files. I'm currently trying to remove the image_list.append(img) step to maybe remove the need to store all of it.